# Wicket JavaScript render sequence

Tags: javascript, wicket

Here is the case.

1. I have a panel. The panel will render "a.js" by overriding `renderHeader()`
2. I have a page. The panel is added in the page. This page will render "b.js" by overriding `renderHeader()`
3. No `RenderHeaderStrategy` is specified. Therefore `ChildFirstRenderHeaderStrategy` is used.

The result on page is:

1. a.js
2. Wicket jQuery
3. b.js

**The expected result should be:**

1. Wicket jQuery
2. b.js
3. a.js

I also tried to use `ParentFirstRenderHeaderStrategy`

The result is:

1. b.js
2. Wicket Jquery
3. a.js

Does anyone know why this happens? What should I do, to get the expected result?

Comment: define that a and b depend on jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete @bert-s comment:

Every class extending `org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ResourceReference`
can overwrite the `getDependencies` method.

You need to specify `org.apache.wicket.settings.def.JavaScriptLibrarySettings#getJQueryReference`
as dependency for a.js and b.js.

An instance of `JavaScriptLibrarySettings` is available in the class which extends the `WebApplication` via `getJavaScriptLibrarySettings`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any change to simply rewrite RenderStrategy to adjust the sequence?